# Can Validation be used with parameters that are enhanced in the controller?

Tags: java, validation, playframework

I have a Website model, that has a `@Required User owner` property. This property gets filled inside the controller method. However, validation is checked upon entering the controller method, so it considers the object invalid (because at the time, it is).

Should Play! validation be used for this purpose?

Should I just drop the @Valid annotation and check manually using `validation.required(website)`?

**Update** - using `validation.required(website)` only validates that the website is not null, but it does not run validate any of the annotations on the website. If I'm not using the @Valid parameter annotation, does this mean I can't use annotation-based validations on the model itself? What's a programmer to do?

**Update2** - it seems I should be calling `validation.valid(website)` instead of `validation.required(website)`. I also added a `@Required` annotation to the `add()` method parameter (instead of @Valid). Is this the way it should be done?

```
@Entity
public class Website extends PortalModel {
    @Required
    public String url;

    @Required
    @ManyToOne
    public User owner;
}

public class Sites extends UserAwareControllerBase {
    public static void added(@Valid Website website) {
        website.owner = getUser(); // from base class

        if (Validation.hasErrors()) {
            Validation.keep();
            params.flash();
            add();
        }

        websiteRepo.save(website);
        edit(website.id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's a point to declare User as @Required if your app's users have no influence on it. Well, it's a safety net for your own code.

But since the user is not in the parameters when you submit the website form, you have to validate manually:

```
website.owner = getUser();
validation.valid(website);
...
```

Comment: The thing is I kind of misinterpreted the validation annotations to hold at all times where the entity is persisted, while they're more like a filter on the Controllers layer. I wish there was some way to enforce validation rules at persistence time using these annotations.

For now though, `validation.valid()` is great, thanks.

Comment: They're both, that's why you can annote inside the Controller AND the model using the same annotation.

Comment: My model is annotated, yet bad objects still got persisted. I just saw this post on how to make sure this does't happen: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/play-framework/MofQCKoZ9RE/2gYrX3l5lOoJ

Comment: I thought I'd seen an error when calling save(), but now you mention it, it was annotated with @Column(unique=true), which is a JPA annotation. In WebObjects this was indeed better, the validation exceptions always came from the model.